# Storing prices in SQLite, what data-type to use?

Tags: datatypes, sqlite, money

I am using SQLite and need to store prices. SQLite's `REAL` data-type says it uses `floating-point` which is *unacceptable* storage for prices. Is there a data-type besides TEXT that I can use to store prices numerically so they sort correctly?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use an integer & store the prices as the lowest common unit. So, for dollars and cents you'd store it in cents. EG: $1.00 would be stored as 100.

In my experience it's standard practice.

Comment: It's extra work but this is the way to go - you also need a currency type field to store with the value so you know how to convert back. You need to pay attention, too - most currencies use 2 decimal places, but some use three. Check out ISO 4127 for the full list.

Comment: CLF Chilean Unidad de Fomento uses 4 decimal places. Bitcoin even more :-)

Answer (score 5):

Certainly, use [integer](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

You will have to decide how many decimal places you are assuming and be consistent at the application level.